# how to use mysql index on left join?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have two tables: authors and books:
books (id, name, auth_id)
authors (id, name).
I have a left join query.

```
SELECT books.name, authors.name
FROM books
LEFT JOIN authors ON books.auth_id = authors.id
ORDER BY books.name
```

How to add index on this left join?

Comment: `alter table books add index auth_id_idx(auth_id);` and `alter table authors add index id_idx(id)`